# Java Enterprise GlassFish Server Error

Tags: java, glassfish

I have an enterprise java project. Everything was fine until I have this error

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener. Please see server.log for more details.

I don't know what this means. I restart the server, the computer and this error still appear.

Comment: Have you checked the `server.log`?

Comment: yes. I try to put it here but i can't because it was to much code and less description

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue,

Cause of Error

1. UnDeploy war1.war
2. Deploy war1.war
3. Deployment failure due to the above error

Workaround

1. Stop domain
2. Clean glassfish\domains\domain1\applications
3. Start domain
4. Deploy now.

Comment: I use service for running the glassfish server in windows and have this issue after stop domain clear all application folder(empty folder) and some other folder from autodeploy without start domain and deploy from eclipse to run the ear file with your steps works fine , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have your persistence xml loaded in your classpath. in Intellij just add it manually through project structure.